# how to refresh form on closing jquery dialog box?

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

This is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#divTimezone").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            height: 270,
            width: 550,
            close: function () {              

            }
        });
        $("#linkCreate").click(function () {
            $("#divTimezone").dialog("open");
        });

    });
</script>
<div id="divTimezone">
    @Html.Partial("_Create", new Aegis.Lisa.Library.Time_Zone())
</div>
```

When i close the modal popup and reopen it then the textbox values, validators values etc are not reset. They remain in the same state as i entered values previously. How to reset the form on close?

Comment: You have to write some javascript code for that.
Can you please post the Html for 'divTimezone' form?

Answer (score 0):

add this before opening the dialog

```
if ( $("#divTimezone") != undefined){

    $("#divTimezone").dialog("destroy").remove();
}
```

like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#linkCreate").click(function () {

        if ( $("#divTimezone") != undefined){

            $("#divTimezone").dialog("destroy").remove();
        }

        $("#divTimezone").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            height: 270,
            width: 550,
            close: function () {              

            }
        });
        $("#divTimezone").dialog("open");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i updated my answer..  try that one. i put the code of creating the dialog after the condition